# SimGrid. How to add additional parameters to masterworker model?

Tags: java, simgrid

What is the best way to complicate masterWorker model from [here](https://github.com/mquinson/simgrid/tree/master/examples/java/app/masterworker)?

How to add following features:
Each worker can execute `n` of task simultaneously (is there any way, except deploying `n` `processes` in deployment.xml file)? Maybe by using `core` attribute in platform.xml?

How to assign `CPU`, `GPU`, `RAM` and `storage` to each worker? How to make time of execution of task to be depending from all above parameters?

**UPDATED**

I use such code: but I can't watch the multi-executing.

```
commReceived = Task.irecv("Tier1_" + num);
commReceived.waitCompletion();
task = commReceived.getTask();
commReceived = null;
task.execute
```

**UPDATED2**

I added comm.test() but it doesn't help for situation when I expect that second core of worker have to receive task from master while first core of worker is executing task.

```
commReceived = Task.irecv("Tier1_" + num);
if (commReceived.test()){
    commReceived.waitCompletion();
    task = commReceived.getTask();
    commReceived = null;
    task.execute()}
```

Answer (score 1):

The classical solution to pass arguments to a process is to serialize the args into strings, and to pass them as parameters of your deployment file. The process will get them in the arguments of its main function.

You really don't want to mess with existing constructs of the platform file, such as the core attribute, because they actually mean something. If you increase the core attribute, the host will become multicore, able to run more than one task at once. That may be what you want of course, and if you want to model storages, then you should use the  tag.

But instead if you just want to attach arbitrary data (that has no impact on the performance of the resource) to an arbitrary platform element (such as hosts, links, clusters or whatever), then go for properties. There is several examples using properties in the archive.

Comment: Can I use VM instead of Process for executing task?

Comment: Adding multi-core doesn't allow receive and execute several tasks at once.

Comment: You cannot use VM to execute a task because a VM in SimGrid is a container. That's not active, that's more similar to an Host than to a Process.

Comment: Multi-core allows you to execute several tasks at once, I promise. But it has nothing to do with the communication side. Use asynchronous comms for that.

Comment: could you help? Where did I make an error? https://pp.vk.me/c625318/v625318287/3c55f/_gIX2b8XG6U.jpg

Comment: I cannot comment on your code. Go debug your code, or ask me questions. What are you trying (MWE), what are you seeing, what were you expecting.